# How to change cursor type on hover in css

Tags: html, css, cursor

I've set my cursor type to crosshair in the body of css, on hover i need it to change to a plain cross, but it still goes to a pointer when i hover over buttons, how do i make it go from a crosshair to cross on hover?

Comment: see this link you may use `url()` for custom cursor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: thank you, but id like it to change to a stock cursor of my choice on hover, I've used the "cursor: crosshar;" in the body of css, but i need to know what tag to use to change the hover cursor, like when you're clicking a button

Comment: do you mean change cursor on hover state like`#one:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}`

Comment: I know about `crosshair` cursor but which one is `plain cross`

Comment: `button:hover{
  cursor: **any-cursor-name**;
}`

Comment: oh! sorry it's `default` like `button:hover{   cursor: default; }`

Comment: i beleive i got mixed up, there is no plain cross cursor, it was on a false list i found, but the principle is the same, id like the cursor to change from crosshair to something else on hover

Comment: actually, i think thats going to work!! thank you so much!!

Comment: is there any way to change the color of the cursor when it hovers also?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can use `cursor: url("custom_colored_cursor.png");` and you welcome. please mark this question answered If the is no any further problem. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you mean this.

```css
#one:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  Hover Me!
  <button>Hover Me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, thank you! but i need it to only change when i hover buttons-

Comment: i think its fixed now!! thank you so much for your help!!